# SQLAlchemy / SQLSoup not seeing temporary tables in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, temp-tables, sqlsoup

I have inherited an SQLQlchemy / SQLSoup application and need to make it scale 20 times.

One query was going really slow, so I refacatored it. Due to MySQL's poor performance on nested subqueries/ derived tables, I split it into two temporary tables and join those.

Now I am trying to add the SQL to the code, but when I try and access the temporary tables, I get an error saying that the table doesn't exist.

```
db.execute("""DROP TABLE IF  EXISTS next_requests""") ;
db.execute("""
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE next_requests
                (INDEX request_id_index (cirId)) 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            cr.uuid             AS cirId,
            ....")

db.execute("SELECT * FROM next_requests")
```

Now I get the error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'SAST.next_requests' (doesn't exist")
```

I assume this is because the session is being closed and re-oped between queries, or something like that.

The database connection is as follows.

```
ENGINE = create_engine(settings.dbString, pool_recycle=1800, pool_size=5)
SESSION = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True,\
    expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=True))
SQLSOUP_DB = sqlsoup.SQLSoup(ENGINE, session=SESSION)
```

(The SQLSOUP_DB is the db used in db.execute).

What do I need to do to keep the session open, so that I can still use the temporary tables. Or is it likely to be something else causing this problem?

Comment: Its faster when I split it in two. The problem is I need the most recent entry in a one to many relationship on a large table, so I need to do a self JOIN on select MAX(). This derived table isn't getting indexed, so everything is going slow.  I have a decent understanding of SQL, just not SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have to use sessions. Wrap the SQL statements like so:

```
session = database.SESSION
with session.begin() : 
    database.execute("Create Temporary Table.....")
    database.execute("Create Temporary Table2.....")
```